# How to work with CordovaActivity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using cordova in my project and I want to get access to some urls. 
    I have a class which extends CordovaActivity class. in Myclass, onCreate() function will be added to myClass automatically when cordova build the project.This class will be generated whenever cordova build the broject. 
   My problem is that my new code will be always disappear in that class when I run cordova build. I also reffer to this class in my create Notificatio function in GCMIntentService class.

Any idea about where I should add my new code to get access to urls?

here is my code:

```
public class Myclass extends CordovaActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }

    // here is my new code that intend to loud a specific page 
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String url = Config.getStartUrl();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            String s = intent.getStringExtra("HTML_PAGE");
            if (s != null) url = s;
        }

        super.loadUrl(url);
    }

    // here is my new code
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }
}
```